# Custom adapter returning nothing in String array

Tags: android

I have a custom spinner in my Android app;

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        resultList.clear();
        listSpinner.clear();
        listSpinner.add("All teams");

        for(DataSnapshot matchSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            matches match = matchSnapshot.getValue(matches.class);
            resultList.add(match);
            listSpinner.add(matchSnapshot.child("homeTeam").getValue().toString());
            listSpinner.add(matchSnapshot.child("awayTeam").getValue().toString());
        }

        listSpinner = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(listSpinner));
        spinnerTitles = listSpinner.toArray(new String[0]);
        CustomAdapter adapterSpin = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), spinnerTitles, spinnerImages, spinnerPopulation);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpin);
        resultList.sort(Comparator.comparing(matches::getDateFormatted).thenComparing(matches::getTime));
        resultList adapter = new resultList (getActivity(), resultList);
        listViewResult.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

This works great for populating the spinner, but when I then attempt to use the spinner, and select a item in the list I keep getting;

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
```

The error is pointing to the forth line below;

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id ) {
            if(++check > 1) {
                String getSpinTeam =(String)parent.getSelectedItem();
                ....
            }
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

When I debug and check the values of what is being returned I can still see 2 records in the array, so I'm confused as to why it errors saying that the Size is 0 when it clearly is telling me something in the debugger.

My question is, this is the first custom spinner I've built, how I have handled the setOnItemSelectedListener is that the common way of handling returned data from the spinner (it is for the built in non-custom version) or have I missed something?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here:

```
String getSpinTeam =(String)parent.getSelectedItem();
```

It must be:

```
String getSpinTeam =(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this, replace:

```
 String getSpinTeam =(String)parent.getSelectedItem();
```

By

```
 String getSpinTeam = spinnerTitles.get(position);
```

Hope this help

Comment: I had to wrap the above in String getSpinTeam = String.valueOf(resultList.get(position)); but whilst it demonstrated a different behaviour (first 2 items were good, but the subsequent ones not as it went out of bounds), there maybe something in this... :)

Comment: The problem is resultList. I edited my answer. Maybe it works now :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried your change, but as its a string array it doesn't have the get method (spinnerTitles is declared as String[] spinnerTitles;). The problem is I originally built this using the built in spinner array adapter, now refactoring it and using a string array is cause the problem (I think) as resultList is a object that I used to describe my array previously and moving to the custom spinner has highlighted it. Thanks again for the help.